# +$ in jquery. How come not only the basic $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code where `+$(...)` is used in many places. The code does not work without the `+` part, when doing just `$(...)`.

I couldn't find any explanation through Google. I'd appreciate any guidance if possible.

```
function calculate() {
  var a = +$('#a').val(); // what is +$ ?
  var b = +$('#b').val();
  var c = b * 108.40;
  //etc
}
```

Comment: It's the other way around , var a += $('#idofinput').val();

Comment: Well it is not in the code I have. It is like I said. Or maybe you mean it should be the other way around?

Comment: `var a += ...` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`+$()` is actually two operations, where first `$()` runs to grab your input and then `+` coerces whatever the value of the input is into a number.

Here's a breakdown of what is happening:

```js
var valueA = $('#a').val(); // "123"
var numberA = +valueA;      //  123

console.log('valueA is a ' + typeof valueA);   // 'valueA is a string'
console.log('numberA is a ' + typeof numberA); // 'numberA is a number'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" value="123"/>
```

Comment: interresting. are numbers in input text field always strings even if numbers?

Comment: @Mik_A yup, input values are always strings.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Got wiser now. Glad I asked. Don't know why I get down votes though.

Comment: @Mik_A No problem amigo. People sometimes downvote without proper consideration of the level of skill the person that is asking the question has, and sometimes they are just mean. You got my upvote if anything :). I also got a downvote for no apparent reason haha. Make sure when you ask a question that you format it nicely and be as precise/detailed as possible in explaining what the problem is and what you tried to solve it, that will prevent most of the the downvoting, I edited your question a bit to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I know I don't always write so accurately :) I did try to find the answer from many places (tutorials) first. So I still think this question can be useful for many others too.